# In Java, how can I print an Object if the Object might be an Integer, int[], String, long[][], etc

Tags: java, oop

I'm writing a block of code that needs to generically output an Object. The Object can be anything, including an array of array of arrays. If it's an array, **it can be an array of primitives**, or of class objects. How can I do this?

Basically:

```
Object x = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
Object y = new int[][]{{},{1,2}};
Object z = "hello";
//etc...
```

Now I want a generic way to print x, y, or z.

For example, for y I would like "{{},{1,2}}"

edit: I see some answers that work if the right hand side is an Object[], but they don't seem to work with primitive arrays

Comment: Another option is to use JSON...

Comment: @jahroy I'm trying to use JSON-Simple, and it's not working. Got any recommendation?

Comment: I haven't used JSON in years.  The last time I did, it was pretty straightforward.  Any class that needed to become JSON simply implemented a JSON method.  This method basically built a String by concatenating the result of calling _.toJSON_ (or something) on each of its properties.

Comment: @jahroy The problem I have there is that the primitive array classes do not have a .toJSON, so they have been defaulting to toString. That merely produces the memory address on the heap

Comment: i think json is what you need, try with gson, it works with objects and primitives

Comment: @mulax Can you have a json example that works with primitive arrays?

Comment: new Gson().toJson(new int[]{1,2,3})

Comment: You could either use one of the many libraries that has already been suggested, or you could write a few VERY simple methods that convert a primitive into a string.  You could overload this method for each primitive (there aren't THAT many) and use that (if you want to roll your own code).

Comment: @mulax I'll give that a shot. The key problem is not whether it works for primitives or objects, but whether it works on Object references that can be either objects OR primitives (OR arrays of either)

Comment: @mulax Post as an answer (with sample and reference link/excerpt) and I'll upvote it. This problem is far too tedious to re-invent again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list):

```
static Gson gs = new Gson();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object obj = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    System.out.println(gs.toJson(obj));
}

// output: [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you!! I will look at the gson source another day =)

Answer (score 2):

1 - [Arrays.deepToString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

2 - [Arrays.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Provide further explanation for your answers.

Comment: @Arcymag `Array.toString` has overloads for all the applicable primitive array types. (But `deepToString` only works with `Object[]`. Java really screwed up its handling of "primitive" values, but that's another story ..)

Comment: @pst This doesn't work if the pointer / reference if of type object. I would need to use instanceof and cast it to a primitive array. (I'm in Java6 if that helps). Here's the error: The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object).

Comment: @Arcymag Ahh, yes. You can instanceof dispatch it back out .. as in Shashank Kadne's answer, only call the method after the appropriate cast.

Comment: So I need to enumerate all primitive array types I suppose? That's ugly =(

Comment: @Arcymag I suspect there are some *existing* reflection approaches that could help: if the format just needs to be "human readable", I would recommend using JSON. This would result in things like "[[],[1,2]]".

Answer (score 0):

Using `instanceof` ?

```
Object x = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
        Object y = new int[][]{{},{1,2}};
        Object z = "hello";

        if(x instanceof int[])
        {
            for(int i:(int[])x)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        if(y instanceof int[][])
        {
             for (int[] arr : (int[][])y) {
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
                }

        }
        if(z instanceof String)
        {
            System.out.println(z);
        }
```

**Update**
I think it will work for Primitives as well if you use the corresponding wrapper class.

```
            byte a =1;
            Object t = a;
            char c = 'c';
            Object j = c;
            if(t instanceof Byte)
            {
                System.out.println(t);
            }

            if(j instanceof Character)
            {
                System.out.println(j);
            }
```

Comment: Does this mean I need to enumerate int[] int[][] and the rest of the primitives (char, short, byte, etc etc?)

Comment: For primitives it won't work. For arrays and Strings it will, as they are Objects.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I need a solution that works for primitives.

Comment: What do yoy mean by Primitive arrays? Arrays are Objects, so you don't even need a wrapper class.

Comment: e.g. Object t = new int[][]{{1,2},{3,4},{5},{}};

Comment: Can you give a block of code that will work for the 3 example objects I listed in the question?

Comment: Oh I see. You want to iterate *every* type. Well, what if it's an int[][][][][][][]. I suppose we can do a recursive version of this, for every single primitive type, and then we can have a method to handle objects. Seems ugly to me.

Answer (score -1):

use toString() it is overriden in every object by default

Comment: (But often not very "pretty", like, well, array objects ..)

Comment: There's no guarantee toString is overridden in a senseful way. Calendar is such an example.

Comment: that will print junk mode in case of array